# How do automated markers exit hasNext in Scanners

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I was doing a programming problem in one of the online programming competition websites. The instructions were that it should continue to get user input (Not from File) while the user has an input to enter. The code more or less was the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (input.hasNext()){
        my_input = input.nextLine();
        *Does some implementation*
    }
}
```

There was no condition or breaks inside the while loop that would allow it to exit. If this was manually run, there would always be a next input. How is it that when I submit my code, the system that assesses my code is able to exit the while loop. I thought it would get stuck in an infinite loop since you can always add another input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect the standard input to read from a file, the loop will exit when the scanner reaches the end of the file.

When the program is reading from the console, you can manually indicate the end of the input stream by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> on Unix (including OSX), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows.

Comment: Yes but I am not talking about a File. If it was a file, I would understand that it would evaluate to false when checking .hasNext(). I am referring to System.in.

Comment: @ashimashi: And I am talking about redirection, where `System.in` comes from the a file: http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html

Comment: @ashimashi And? `System.in` *could* be anything (i.e. any `InputStream`).